# Can I make a JavaScript object return an arbitrary value instead of returning itself?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create an object in JavaScript that returns an arbitrary value rather than returning itself?

For example:

```js
function myCollection() {
  var items = []

  return {
    push: function(value) {
      value += 'bar'
      items.push(value)
    },

    toReturn: function() {
      return items
    }
  }
}

var fooCollection = myCollection()

fooCollection.push('foo')

return fooCollection // is there a way to make this return ['foobar']?
```

So, I want to make an object that works like a JavaScript array. An array has methods but when you return an array, you get array values. You don't get an object.

Comment: An object doesn't "return".

Comment: @dystroy so it's not possible to build an object that works like a JavaScript array in that it has methods but when you return it you get some other value?

Comment: _"when you return an array, you get array values. You don't get an object."_ - No, if you return an array you get the object that is that array, not the individual elements. Please be clearer about what you mean by "return" - your code as shown is invalid because the final `return fooCollection` is not inside a function.

Comment: Do you mean [`var arr = fooCollection.toReturn();`](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/9NB68/)? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: @Andy Like `toString` gets called when you implicitly coerce an object into a string, I was hoping there's something like that that gets called when you return the object. That's why I called the method `toReturn`. I don't want to call `toReturn` explicitly. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: If you've already tried defining a `toString()` function for your object and that didn't work, I'd suggest you try defining a `valueOf()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried `valueOf`. It doesn't do it.

Comment: Can you please update your question to show exactly how you're trying to use the object after it is "returned"? `return fooCollection` doesn't make sense (or is actually an error) when used outside of a function as shown, but even if that was in a function it would return a reference to the object just as `return []` returns a reference to an array. You need to show the code that uses whatever is returned.

Comment: @nnnnnn if I succeed in returning the array of items instead of the actual object. I'd use it as an array. The code in the OP actually works but returns a different value from what I hope it would.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `myCollection` function enrich the `items` array with whatever new methods you want, and then just return `items`.

```
function myCollection() {

    var items = [];

    items.push = function (value) {
        value += "bar";

        // call Array's push method to push new value onto items
        Array.prototype.push.call(items, value);
    };

    return items;
};

var fooCollection = myCollection();

fooCollection.push('foo');

console.log(fooCollection); // logs ['foobar', push: function]
```

A problem with this is that when you log `fooCollection`, it logs the contents of the array, but it also logs the new `push` method.

Luckily, the `fooCollection` above would still have length `1`, and `fooCollection[0]` would still be `'foobar'`.  So this `push` property in the log output probably wouldn't get in the way of using `fooCollection` as an array.

Alternately, you could define a `MyCollection` class which extends `Array`, and redefines whatever methods you want.

In my opinion this way is more javascripty than the above.  Above, each time you call `myCollection`, you create an `Array` object and redefine its `push` method.  Here, you only define the custom `push` method once: on the `MyCollection` class.

```
// define a MyCollection class that inherits from array
function MyCollection() {
};

MyCollection.prototype = new Array;


// add custom 'push' method to MyCollection class
MyCollection.prototype.push = function (value) {
    value += "bar";
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, value);
};


var fooCollection = new MyCollection();

fooCollection.push('foo');

console.log(fooCollection); // logs ['foobar', push: function]
```

Comment: That's interesting and it's pretty close to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do that. Return can be used for nothing but specifying the return value of a function. source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your object to be *array-like*, you can do this :

```
function myCollection() {
  var items = [], r = {}
  function myPush(value){
      value += 'bar'
      r[items.length]=value;
      items.push(value)    
  }
  Object.defineProperty(r, "splice", {value:[].splice});
  Object.defineProperty(r, "slice", {value:[].slice});
  Object.defineProperty(r, "length", {
    get : function(){ return items.length}
  });
  Object.defineProperty(r, "myPush", {value:myPush});
  return r;
}

var fooCollection = myCollection();
fooCollection.myPush('foo');
console.log(fooCollection); // logs ["foobar"] 
fooCollection.myPush('Ba');
console.log(fooCollection); // logs ["foobar", "Babar"] 

fooCollection.myPush('wzouing');
console.log(fooCollection.slice(-2)); // logs ["Babar", "wzouingbar"] 
console.log(fooCollection[1]); // logs Babar
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/wefaf/3/edit)

Comment: It's logging `{ '0': 'foobar' }` and `{ '0': 'foobar', '1': 'Babar' }` for me.

Comment: Open the link again **and do click the "Run with JS" button**.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. In JS Bin it's working, but I'm also trying this in Node.js and it's logging out objects, except for the log line with `slice` method. That one is logging out an array.

Comment: What's the real goal ? Just logging ?

Comment: The real goal is to make an object that works like the String or Array native objects where the return value is not an object, but some value  and still have some methods that operate on the object.

Comment: That's not the goal, that's an intermediate step in a path you think you lead to your goal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48589/discussion-between-mk-safi-and-dystroy)